# FTP sites/all and sites/default/files files zipped and unzip on server or FTP as is?

Tags: installation, files

I have cpanel with hostgator, and it's faster to zip the folder sites/all and sites/default/files and then unzip on the server.

Is that the best way to do things or can it get corrupted?

Is it safer to FTP the files as is from the localhost environment?

Comment: The question is better suited for [ProWebmaster](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/); as is, it's not related to Drupal.

Comment: i mean...it *is* related to Drupal. that queue might have more specific details re: security, performance, corruption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first recommendation is for /sites/all that you use a version control system such as Git/Subversion to save then the pull changes. If you *must* FTP them, I've found it's just as easy to copy them all over at once rather than unpack on the server, mostly because shared host SSH capabilities are sporadic and semi-functional at best.

Things to be careful of: if you're literally copying over /sites/default/files make sure that any .htaccess files were also copied. Additionally, you'll for sure have to do a cache clear because any css or js files saved in those directories will be unlinked from the current database.

Comment: " Additionally, you'll for sure have to do a cache clear because any css or js files saved in those directories will be unlinked from the current database." = Does that mean doing a drush cc all, before doing the FTP?

Comment: Well you could do a cache clear before uploading the files, but I would also do one once you have it all in place.